# Set visibility for all ImageViews in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

**SOLVED** - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637809/Задать-setvisibility-всем-imageview-в-recyclerview-Вызов-метода-адаптера-из-акт#637817](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637809/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-setvisibility-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-imageview-%D0%B2-recyclerview-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82#637817)

I have RV item layout with ImageView, which is responsible for the Drag&Drop operation. By default I want make them **not visible** and by clicking on the button in the menu in the toolbar make **visible**, so that the user can move the items in RV.

So tell me please how can I set visibility for all necessary ImageViews in RVAdapter. **I need to call method with setting visibility from my MainActivity.**

**Item's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/rv_card"
        style="@style/MainCardStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/station_logo"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/avtoradio_logo"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/station_name"
                    style="@style/MainTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Европа плюс"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/station_freq"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="105,3 FM"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_card_small_text_color"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
            </LinearLayout>


        // This ImageView I need to make visible
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dragView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="13dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_drag_album"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewHolder class**

```
public static class StationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        CardView cardView;
        TextView stationName;
        TextView stationFrequency;
        ImageView stationLogo;
        ImageView dragView;

        StationViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            final Context context = itemView.getContext();
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_card);
            stationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
            stationFrequency = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_freq);
            stationLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_logo);
            dragView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dragView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the visibility as true or Visible of the Linerlayout or CardView that u have taken as the parent layout

Comment: @SnehalGongle in xml? I already do this. By default they are GONE, but I need nethod, which set VISIBLE for all necessary ImageViews. If I setting visibility of ImageView by ID in MainActivity, it applied only for first item in RecyclerView

Comment: CardView cardView=findViewById(R.id.rv_card);
        cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        try this or only Visible or itemView.Visible instead of view.visible      so do not do it on the image view do to its parent layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one method in Adapter class which has dome flag and according value of flag you can visible and gone `ImageView` .
you can add one if condition in your `StationViewHolder` .

You need to notify your Adapter.

Comment: But how can I call method from StationViewHolder in my Activity class?

Comment: You need to notify your Adapter.

Comment: Can you give me some sample?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        dragView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: I need set visibility from Activity class by clicking on the item in the toolbar menu.

Comment: You need to set it onItemClicked().

Comment: But I don't click on item.

Comment: You have mentioned this in your post.
"by clicking on the button in the menu in the toolbar make visible"
On this click event you can make is Visible.

Comment: I added it to my code. Is works only if I click on RecyclerView's item, bu not if click on toolbar's menu item.

Comment: Yes, it cant find the ID of imageview which is inside adapter.
So on itemClick() take a boolean as true and change visiblity inside Adapter.